# How can I center my page but put it at the bottom

Tags: html, css

```
.helpdesk ul {
width:750px;
list-style-type:none;
list-style-position:outside;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
text-align: center;
bottom: 100px;

}
.helpdesk li{
padding:12px; 
border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
position:relative; 
text-align: center
bottom: 100px;
center: 20px;
}

.helpdesk h2 {
margin: o;
display: inline;
}


.helpdesk label {
width:150px;
margin-top: 3px;
display:inline-block;

padding:3px;
text-align: center;
bottom: 100px;
}





   <ul>
  <li>
     <h2>Help Desk</h2>

  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Doe"/>
  </li>

 <li>
   <label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="JohnDoe@example.com" />
</li> 
<li>
<label for="website">Phone Number:</label>
<input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="###-###-####" />

</li> 
<li>
<label for="message">Message:</label>
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6"> 
</textarea>
</li>
  <li>
  <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit </button>
  </li>
   </ul>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to move my UL and Li to the middle bottom of the page can't seem to get it right, is there anyway to do this. I'm tried looking online and its only giving me the bottom left or bottom right, when I need bottom center

Comment: any fiddle or code or any example to begin with???

Comment: Add your html please.

Comment: What does the html container around the ul look like?

Answer (score 0):

add style rule `margin:auto` to .helpdesk ul selector